# how do I get two column layout with left having 2 rows in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need a layout to look like this:
[image]

How can I achieve that look (each column is 50% of the whole page and same for each row on the left).

I'm trying use container-fluid and row-fluid. Here is what I have tried, but the purple part...is much lower on the page. Offset but not the same level as the left.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div id="top" class="span6"></div>
  </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <div id="bottom" class="span6"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <div id="canvas" class="span6 offset6"></div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Take this structure [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kz5Xj/1/) and ajust your code. If you need to adapt the height of the div's, you will need some css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html) search for nesting columns

It will end up similar to this (untested)

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background:yellow;height:400px;">
  <div class="row-fluid" style="height:100%;border:1px solid #aaa;">
    <div class="span6" style="height:100%;">
      <div class="row-fluid" style="height:50%;">
        <div class="span12" style="background:blue;height:100%;">a</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row-fluid" style="height:50%;">
        <div class="span12" style="background:red;height:100%;">b</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    Right side
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This markup should fit your needs,

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12 red">test</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span12 red">test</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span6 blue">
            test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    .red
    {
        background-color: red;
        min-height:200px;
    }
    .blue
    {
        background-color: blue;
        min-height:200px;
    }
    </style>
```

In order to remove the left margin you simply need to override the default bootstrap css.